# What does maximum frequency range really mean in an inductor?

Tags: inductor

I'm trying to decide whether or not to order several 0.22uH inductors from http://www.futurlec.com/Inductors.shtml for my radio application where the frequency is well over 100Mhz.

The website states: "Frequency Range Up to 1MHz"

How is this possible when an inductor is really wire wrapped around something? or does that refer to something else?

Comment: parasitic capacitance loss, core material loss, skin effect loss - take your pick. In this case I'd be thinking loss due to the type of core material used limiting the upper frequency (energy lost per cycle due to hysteresis).

Comment: Look at coilcraft for RF inductors if you're in the US. The 1 MHz reference might be the self resonant frequency of this inductor, i.e., where it resonates with the parasitic coil capacitances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the frequency range over which it meets its stated specifications. Outside that range, parasitic effects start to become significant; with inductors, the primary problem is the distributed capacitance among the windings, which creates a parallel-resonant circuit that causes the impedance to rise anomalously near resonance.

If the inductor has a core, losses in the core can become significant, too. This appears as an effective resistance in parallel with the inductor, reducing its "Q" or quality factor.

Answer (score 3):

Some combination of winding capacitance and core material losses.

I would be surprised if a part specified for 1MHz was satisfactory at 100MHz unless you were using it as an RFC or something where the losses may be a good thing.

However I given the lack of a datasheet of any meaningful kind, who really knows, that 1MHz may apply to the highest available value or to one in the middle of the range, but this number is usually one that varies with value, so using a bottom of the range 220nH part, you may get away with it. 
Personally, I would pick something from a supplier with proper datasheets, life is too short to be messing with poorly specified parts when you don't have to.

73